# How to Make Select Element be Transparent in Chrome?

Tags: css, select, google-chrome

Please look this example:

```css
select {
  width: 172px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 2px 7px;
  border: none;
  background: url(http://imgur.com/MJyZM.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="abcdefg">abcdefg</option>
  <option value="1234567">1234567</option>
  <option value="abcdefg">abcdefg</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeafgilbert/wz0zaev0/

Can someone please update it to be transparent in Chrome? Currently the result in FF is the correct one. Thanks.

**Update:**

Now without `-webkit-appearance: none;` works fine in Chrome.

Comment: The jsfiddle link is not working. Can you please update it?

Comment: @DragosRizescu Updated the fiddle link, the answer is `-webkit-appearance: none;` but it's not needed anymore for updated Chrome.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```css
select {
  width:192px;
  padding:2px;
  border:none;
  background:url(http://imgur.com/MJyZM.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="abcdefg">abcdefg</option>
  <option value="1234567">1234567</option>
  <option value="abcdefg">abcdefg</option>
</select>
```

Not tested on firefox but it seems `-webkit-appearance: none;` disables specific behaviours webkit can apply.

Comment: Thanks! that just saved me a couple of hours of frustration. +1