# How to set Select box background in WebKit?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to set Select box of transparent background

I used CSS of `select {background: transparent}`

But it not working. how do I do?

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with

Comment: by transparent do u mean opacity reduced?

Comment: http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles checkout styles here.

Comment: this question is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

That is if you want to create a transparent select tag

Comment: I don't think use the opacity can set a transparent background select, Because it will select box and text and borders are transparent

Comment: Oh now i understand your question better. simply use a transparent image in your background

Comment: I tried this CSS background: url(images/transparent.gif), It not working why?

Comment: a transparent background always work. most overlays use transparent backgrounds in css2. are you testing in IE7 or less? not that is matters really but i have always preferred pngs when it comes to transparency