# What is the correct "-moz-appearance" value to hide dropdown arrow of a <select> element

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, gecko

I'm trying to style the dropdown arrow of a `<select>` element with CSS only , it works perfectly in Chrome/Safari:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;

  background-image: url('./select-arrow1.png') ;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Which renders beautifully [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dfna.jpg)

By that logic, the only thing I had to do to make it work in Firefox was to add all `-webkit-*` stuff as `-moz-*` :

```
-moz-appearance: button;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-padding-end: 20px;
-moz-padding-start: 2px;
-moz-user-select: none;
```

It works for 99%, the only problem is that the default dropdown arrow doesn't go away, and stays on top of the background image [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmaUo.jpg)

It looks like `-moz-appearance: button;` does not work for a `<select>` element. Also `-moz-appearance: none;` has no effect to remove the default dropdown arrow.

So what is the correct value for `-moz-appearance` to remove the default dropdown arrow?

## Updates:

**December 11, 2014**: **Stop inventing new hacks**. After 4 and a half years, `-moz-appearance:none` is starting to work since Firefox 35. Although `moz-appearance:button` is still broken, you don't need to use it anyway. [Here is a very basic working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/88rpe9ze/)

**April 28, 2014**: The mentioned [css hack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666) worked for a couple of months but since the begining of April 2014 this bug is creeping back into Firefox 31.0.a1 Nightly on all platforms.

Comment: Just to let you know the bug has been fixed in Firefox 35 \o/

Comment: @MatTheCat wow after 4.5 years! In the mean time I have changed 2 girl friends, 3 dogs and 2 apartments. But I guess we must be thankful that they finally half-fixed it anyway.

Comment: This means that < FF35 we need to HIDE either our custom arrow or the default. Otherwise you will see both arrows.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is it guys! **FIXED!**

---

Wait and see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

or [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666)

---

For those wondering:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c59

> First, because the bug has a lot of hostile spam in it, it creates a hostile workplace for anyone who gets assigned to this.
>
> Secondly, the person who has the ability to do this (which includes rewriting ) has been allocated to another project (b2g) for the time being and wont have time until that project get nearer to completion.
>
> Third, even when that person has the time again, there is no guarantee that this will be a priority because, despite webkit having this, it breaks the spec for how  is supposed to work (This is what I was told, I do not personally know the spec)

Now see https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Schedule_Roadmap ;)

---

The page no longer exists and the bug hasn't be fixed but [an acceptable workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666) came from João Cunha, you guys can thank him for now!

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it will be fixed soon. As a workaround, I'll be using [the original code in the other question you answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome/)

Comment: Geez, one year later and it seems we can still wait.

Comment: yes, it's pretty sad that after 1 and half year, the status of this bug report stays at "NEW"

Comment: Oh the dreaded "list-style-position" bug.I used to hack around that by assigning a `display: inline` to the header element. In the meantime, I completely moved on to Chromium and try to avoid Firefox as much as I can.

Comment: two year now... thats why we have Chrome!

Comment: The reply from Mozilla mentioned by MatTheCat is really appalling. What they're basically saying is: "We Are Awesome. Put up or shut up."

Comment: The bug is still unfixed, but I figured out a workaround, check my answer here.

And the bug ticket also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c84

Comment: I added a link to your answer, you deserve visibility for your trick!

Comment: Ha! I find it pretty funny (and sad) that people are now implementing these kind of hacks to fix basic CSS bugs in what is called an open source browser engine! Only because the powers that be refuse to fix this bug. Reminds me of all those IE6 hacks people were inventing...

Answer (score 99):

***Update:*** this was fixed in Firefox v35. See the [full gist](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016) for details.

---

== **how to hide the select arrow in Firefox** ==

Just figured out how to do it. The trick is to use a mix of `-prefix-appearance`, `text-indent` and `text-overflow`. It is pure CSS and requires no extra markup.

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Long story short, by pushing it a tiny bit to the right, the overflow gets rid of the arrow. Pretty neat, huh?

More details on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016) I just wrote. Tested on Ubuntu, Mac and Windows, all with recent Firefox versions.

Comment: This is a good work around, but it doesn't seem to push the arrow off enough when the user changes the viewport to anything less than 100%

Comment: Yes, it does, @MathiasaurusRex. Which OS and browser version are you testing it? I'm working on a responsive form at this very moment and I just confirmed.

Comment: @JoãoCunha Sorry, I misspoke. I meant reducing the viewport zoom to anything under 100%. I'm using FireFox 26.0 and running on OSX 10.9.1, Here's a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2Vtf9/1/

Hitting command minus (-) which reduces the zoom to 90% will cause the dropdown arrow to show.

Comment: Not too much of an issue, because the fix is kind of a hack anyway and mozilla just needs to fix the bug. Your fix and the way it reacts to zoom does seem logical to me!

Comment: Hey, nice finding! Will update my gist accordingly :)

https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016

Comment: I would just like to point out that this workaround no longer works as of Firefox 31 (nightly build, may 2014). As far as I know, there is no workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the default dropdown arrow use:

```
-moz-appearance: window;
```

Comment: That's not even a valid value, according to the values listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance and needless to say it doesn't work: http://i.imgur.com/w4hwD.jpg

Comment: Works on MacOS/Firefox v 19.0.2

Comment: This certainly worked for me. MacOS 10.9/Firefox33.0

Comment: Only works on Mac OSX for some strange reason, definitely doesnt work on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Try putting opacity:0; your select element will be invisible but the options will be visible when you click on it.

Comment: If the select element is invisible, how are we supposed to click on the options? By putting a wide background image on the select? And how do you know which option you just selected? By putting an onchange event and update some text on the page? I'm sorry but this is not an answer at all. It's a hairy giant hack.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X, `-moz-appearance: window;`  will remove the arrow accrding to the [MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs) documentation *[appearance (-moz-appearance, -webkit-appearance)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance)*.

It was tested on Firefox 13 on [Mac OS X v10.8.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion). Also see: *[649849 - Make -moz-appearance:none on a combobox remove the dropdown button](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c21)*.

Comment: Works on a Mac but not Windows. Good effort though.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth trying these two options below while we're still waiting for the fix in Firefox 35:

```css
select {
    -moz-appearance: scrollbartrack-vertical;
}
```

Or

```css
select {
    -moz-appearance: treeview;
}
```

They will just hide any arrow background image you have put in to custom style your select element. So you get a bog-standard browser arrow instead of a horrible combination of both the browser arrow and your own custom arrow.

Answer (score -2):

While you can't yet get Firefox to remove the dropdown arrow (see MatTheCat's post), you can hide your "stylized" background image from showing in Firefox.

```
-moz-background-position: -9999px -9999px!important;
```

This will position it out of frame, leaving you with the default select box arrow – while keeping the stylized version in Webkit.

Comment: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: there's no such thing as `-moz-background-position`

Comment: you can however do
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {
        background-position: -9999px!important;
    }
 }

Answer (score -3):

it is working when adding :

select { width:115% }

Comment: This is should be a comment.