# custom drop down not working IE and Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox

I have a custom img for my dropdown option menu and i tried other browser like Internet Explorer and FireFox...

My Code:

```
textarea {
    background: #9d9d9d;
    color: #000000;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.styled-select {
   width: 88%;
   height: 30px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url('../img/down.png') no-repeat right #9d9d9d;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

[image: This is the drop down on firefox]

[image: This is the Drop Down on Internet Explorer]

First Img is for Firefox the Second img is for Internet Explorer

Comment: sorry for my bad english i tried my best...

Comment: Please provide us with your html code. Because it seems like a select element where as you use textarea in your css.

Comment: My JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/patricksterza/A3CLn/

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select

Comment: Thank you so much pmminov sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For I.E:

```
select::-ms-expand
{  
 display: none;
}
```

For Firefox:

```
.select
{
-moz-appearance: none; 
 appearance: none;    
 text-overflow: ''; 
}
```