# Removing select arrow from ie8 print stylesheet

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I have a print style sheet for my site which prints the basics of a calculation (inputs & outputs).
I've successfully removed all the form elements across browsers apart from IE8 which refuses to remove the down arrow from the `select` inputs.

So far my code looks like this:

```
select {
  width: 80px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Works in Firefox & Chrome but not IE8.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: make `width: 0 px` for IE8 ? OR `text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666

Comment: @Ani - this doesn't work, width: 0px would hide the content and text0-indent etc, has no effect on print. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you use it in `@media print` ?