# Select background white/transparent - Chrome OSx

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, html-select

For the life of me I can't remove the background/box shadow on a select box in Chrome on OSx. I need it to be flat white like the other inputs. Take a look here:

http://index1.staging.homeflow.co.uk/pdrum/register.html

Some code in use that isn't doing the job:

```
background: #ffffff;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#ffffff));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, white);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0px);
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
:-webkit-autofill { color: #fff !important; }
```

You may also want to use:

```
select:focus { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `-webkit-appearance: inherit;` on `#pd-signin select` removed it for me.
Then it seems you would need to add some arrow to indicate it is a drop-down.

**Also in regards to SW4's comment:**

I would not remove the outline on any focussed element as this is poor for accessibility.

**Also refer to this article from Chris Coyier**

[Dropdown default styling - Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

**Firefox**

```
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
```

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666)

Comment: This seems to do the job, and I can position a little arrow behind the default one in Firefox. -moz-appearance: none; doesn't appear to hide the default?

Comment: Updated original answer to include the Firefox fix.