# Firefox dropdown arrows when border is 0px on each element and 1px on select

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, select

I have a weird problem with firefox with the following css :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
}
```

In chrome this behaves correctly :

[image: all options on chrome correct]

But in Firefox I get this :

[image: all options on chrome not correct]

When I remove the "border: 0" and "border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;" properties, it works fine :

[image: all options firefox correct]

Any suggestion on how to get the same display on chrome and firefox ? Thanks

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666

Comment: I've already checked this one. I don't want to remove arrows, I just want to display them like in the screenshot, with a padding between the text and the arrows

Comment: why not style it with your own arrow?

Comment: A good read: [The Problem Of CSS Form Elements](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/27/css-form-elements-problem/)

Comment: This might make life easier: http://formalize.me/

Comment: Thank you for the links, interesting reading by the way. Unfortunately, they do not resolve the problem. I ended up using a workaround (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

every browser have it's own css, we have to set some css according to browser you can  use

```
-moz-appearance: none;
```

for this

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And removed this property :

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
}
```

By doing this, each element has it's border handled by the browser. If I don't need a border for an element, I simply put "border: none" in it's properties.

The question is still open as this solution doesn't really resolve the original problem.