# How to remove the drop down arrow in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

How can I remove the drop down arrow normally displayed by FireFox? I have uploaded an image of what I am working with below:

[image]

I am using this css:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
  .class select { width: 110%; }
}

.class > select {
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    text-indent: 0.01px !important;
    text-overflow: "" !important;
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox - Possible duplicate?

Comment: Or you can read the comments on this page as well: https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016

Comment: i have use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox code but it is not working.

Comment: There used to be a commonly used [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select) which worked well until it stopped working overnight since Mozilla 30.0, I've been stranded by this ever since.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that way. Best way is to fake it and create your own customized `<select>`.

Have a look at this fiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/JayKandari/FWLRw/5/

Answer (score 0):

This trick stopped working as of Firefox 30 realeased in 2014-06-10.
You can [upvote the bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849) for a definitive fix.

**Option 1:**
Remove the custom styles on Firefox only through a url-prefix media query, like:

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
       select {
       background-image: none;
    }
```

**Option 2:**

Here is a [solution](http://codepen.io/keksa/pen/hpqyx)