# moz-appearance is not working it seems

Tags: html, css, firefox

i have style my `select box` and its working fine on chrome and safari.

now my problem is in FF i can still see the dropdown arrow with my select box.

i have tried to refer [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787667/what-is-the-correct-moz-appearance-value-to-hide-dropdown-arrow-of-a-select#answer-18327666) and [this solutions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849) but it didn't help me.

Code :

```
  <select placeholder="Search" name="search_cat" class="search_select">
     <option value="">Everything</option>
     <option value="resource">Resources</option>
     <option value="734">Blog Posts</option>
     <option value="8">Pictures</option>
   </select>
```

css :

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("Search-bar-Arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 70px center #80B83B;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 27px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px 0; 
  vertical-align: top;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: "";
  width: 91px;
```

do anyone have trick or solution for this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @janaspage have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of what you expect in final.

you could try to use a basic oldish method with negative margin, float and an extra element as a mask .A pseudo element can be used as a mask to add an image or icone. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nKuhs/)**

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px outset;
  overflow:hidden;/*where no pseudo is used;*/
}
div.pseudo:before {
  content:'⇓';
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  width:1.1em;
  height:1.3em;
  background:tomato;
  position:relative;
}
select {
  margin-right:-1.25em;
  margin-left:-1px;
  border:none;
}
```

You could see to serve this only to mozilla : **[DEMO2](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/avkCp)**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    div {
      display:inline-block;
      border:1px outset;
      overflow:hidden;/*where no pseudo is used;*/
    }
    div.pseudo:before {
      content:'⇓';
      text-align:center;
      float:right;
      width:1.1em;
      height:1.3em;
      background:tomato;
      position:relative;
    }
    select {
      margin-right:-1.25em;
      margin-left:-1px;
      border:none;
    } 
}
```