# Select (expand) a dropmenu when clicking on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div containing a select menu and another element (*.dropArrow*).

What I would like to do is select the menu when you click on .dropArrow.

Here's the jquery I've tried so far but with no success...

```
$(".dropArrow").live('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings("select").click();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="selectContainer selectTest" style="width: 305px;">
    <select id="selectTest">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <span class="dropArrow">^</span>
</div>
```

I'm guessing it's the .click() part that's wrong as I can change that to something like .hide() and it works fine.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of html as well. Also, which version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` is deprecated, and you should probably use `.on()`

Comment: sorry re-read your question and I don't think what you want is possible, doesn't seem to be triggered on element click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work, using just CSS, no Javascript. However I don't think this solution is 100% perfect.

See for yourself at: [jsfiddle.net/Luuk/35xdx/](http://jsfiddle.net/Luuk/35xdx/1/)

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360431/can-i-open-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery) explains more about activating select elements with Javascript

Comment: oh! the `pointer-events: none;` option seems to work in everything except IE. Is there an IE fix at all?

Comment: No, however you can use the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome
Basically you would give your select a different background, and in it you can put your arrow, of course the arrow would have to become an image.