# Select arrow style change

Tags: css, select

I'm trying to replace the arrow of a select with a picture of my own. I'm including the select in a div with the same size, I set the background of the select as transparent and I'm including a picture(with the same size as the arrow) in the right top corner of the div as background.

It only works in Chrome.

[image]

How can I make it work in Firefox and IE9 where I'm getting this:

[image]

```css
.styled-select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  background: url(images/downarrow_blue.png) no-repeat right white;
  border: 2px double red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 0;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.block label {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <p/>
  <form action="/prepareUpdateCategoryList.do?forwardto=search">

    <fieldset class="block" id="searchBlock">
      <p>
        <label style="width:80px">Class</label>
        <div class="styled-select">
          <select property="voucherCategoryClass">
      <option value="0">Select </option>
      <option value="7382">steam </option>
     </select>
        </div>

      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Add `appearance:none;` for your select tag :)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
.styled-select select {
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
    appearance:none;
}
```

Haven't tested, but should work.

**EDIT**: It looks like Firefox doesn't support this feature up until version 35 ([read more here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849))

There is a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome/), take a look at `jsfiddle` on that post.

Comment: what about Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Take a look at @Peter Drinnan's solution for IE

Comment: I found this answer from a duplicate question that shows how to actually add a "button" as well, using pure CSS (no pngs, jpegs, etc.) http://stackoverflow.com/a/28274325/2098017

Comment: The jsfiddle from the 'workaround' question no longer works.

Comment: For show bulbs, use this: `appearance: menulist !important;-moz-appearance: menulist !important;-webkit-appearance: menulist !important;-o-appearance: menulist !important;`

Answer (score 193):

I have set up a `select` with a custom arrow similar to Julio's answer, however it doesn't have a set width and uses an `svg` as a background image. (`arrow_drop_down` from material-ui icons)

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 100%;
  background-position-y: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
```

[image]

If you need it to also work in IE update the svg arrow to base64 and add the following:

```
select::-ms-expand { display: none; }

background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
```

To make it easier to size and space the arrow, use this svg:

```
url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='m0,6l12,12l12,-12l-24,0z'/><path fill='none' d='m0,0l24,0l0,24l-24,0l0,-24z'/></svg>");
```

It doesn't have any spacing on the arrow's sides.

Comment: you could position the arrow more precisely using ```background-position: top 5px right 4px;```

Comment: Zipped: `background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>') 100% 50% no-repeat transparent;`

Comment: may I know why do you use `background-position-y: 5px;` instead of % (eg. `background-position-y: 50%;`)?

Comment: Don't use exadecimal colors in fill attribute, only color names like black, red, blue...

Comment: @AndreaMattioli why can we not use hexadecimal colors?

Comment: @lobati You can use hexadecimal colours. Just replace the hash symbol with `%23`.

Answer (score 66):

Working with just one class:

```
select {
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position-x: 244px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhCsJ/4120/

Comment: Your answer seems to be the most straight forward and uses only css.

Comment: For what it's worth you don't have to set the width of the field and can use % for the background position also :)

Comment: Firefox doesn't support background-position-x, but it supports background-position

Comment: Shame this answer needs so much tweaking :-/ But it's a good starting line.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on setting a width for the control, but still want to pad the image back from the right hand side, you could use calc: eg `background-position-x: calc( 100% - 5px );`

Comment: Thanks god for Chrome!

Comment: also can i change the color the svg ?

Answer (score 47):

```
/* FIX OF UGLY SELECT */
SELECT {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg height='10px' width='10px' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23000000' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7.247 11.14 2.451 5.658C1.885 5.013 2.345 4 3.204 4h9.592a1 1 0 0 1 .753 1.659l-4.796 5.48a1 1 0 0 1-1.506 0z'/></svg>") no-repeat;
    background-position: calc(100% - 0.75rem) center !important;
    -moz-appearance:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important; 
    appearance: none !important;
    padding-right: 2rem !important;
}
```

Adjust variables to match your form styling.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Opera:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

p.s. Form & Input design via Bootstrap 4

Comment: You have given the great examples ...!!!!

Comment: This is GOLD!! Literally spent one full day on how to do this and this is what FINALLY worked!!!

Comment: i love this ,  simple and elegant

Answer (score 32):

Here is an elegant fix that uses a span to show the value.

Layout is like this:

```
<div class="selectDiv">
   <span class="selectDefault"></span>
   <select name="txtCountry" class="selectBox">
      <option class="defualt-text">-- Select Country --</option>
      <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
      <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narensrinivasans/FpNxn/1/)

Comment: +1 for this solution, it is the only way I've found to style the arrows properly on IE9 and older browsers. There are a lot of sites which simply say you can't style select boxes on IE9 and previous, and instead offer fallback strategies, but this solution proves otherwise.

Comment: It's worth mentioning: **this solution requires javascript**, which this answer *is not tagged for*.

Answer (score 25):

This would work well especially for those using Bootstrap, tested in latest browser versions:

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Some browsers will not display the caret when using calc, so we put the fallback first */ 
  background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") white no-repeat 98.5% !important; /* !important used for overriding all other customisations */
  background: url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") white no-repeat calc(100% - 10px) !important; /* Better placement regardless of input width */
}
/*For IE*/
select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
       <option>Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Check this one 
It's hacky, simple as that:

- Set `-prefix-appearance` to `none` to remove the styles
- Use `text-indent` to "push" the content a bit to the right
- Finally, set `text-overflow` to an empty string. Everything that extends beyond it's width will become... nothing! And that includes the arrow.

Now you're free to style it any way you want :)

```css
.selectParent {
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.selectParent select {
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat 60px center;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectParent">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEt5k/1/)

Answer (score 13):

```css
.select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 98%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I wanna clear something that no one mention before I think.

1. First get your `svg` image or icon
2. There you will get some xml code like these `<svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M4 10.127L12 18.127L20 10.127H4Z" fill="#8E8E93"/> </svg>`  try to find it.
3. And past it after this code `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,`
4. Replace the fill color `fill="#8E8E93"` to this `fill="%238E8E93"` If you want to add hexadecmal color you should change `#` to `%23`

Here is the html code:

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="editName">Country</label>
  <select class="ra-select">
    <option value="bangladesh" selected>Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="saudi arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="us">Uinited State Of America</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.ra-select {
   width: 30%;
   padding: 10px;
   /* Replace Default styling (arrow) */
   appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M4 10.127L12 18.127L20 10.127H4Z" fill="%238E8E93"/></svg>');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position-y: 50%;
   background-position-x: 98%;
}

.ra-select:focus,
.ra-select:hover {
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.ra-select option {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Okay, it seems there are a lot of answers here. Some maybe better than others. Incase someone was desperate enough to scroll down here, here's my two cents:

If you really want to style your dropdown, don't use `<select>`. `div` with a regular `<ul>` inside it will be a lot more flexible. However, if you really insist on using select because you just want the most minimal dropdown, here's mine:

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  background: white;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16px' height='16px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M6.1018 8C5.02785 8 4.45387 9.2649 5.16108 10.0731L10.6829 16.3838C11.3801 17.1806 12.6197 17.1806 13.3169 16.3838L18.8388 10.0731C19.5459 9.2649 18.972 8 17.898 8H6.1018Z' fill='%23212121'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0.5rem center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0.25rem 2rem 0.25rem 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
  <select>
    <option value="bottom-right">Bottom right</option>
    <option value="bottom-left">Bottom left</option>
    <option value="top-right">Top right</option>
    <option value="top-left">Top left</option>
  </select>
```

So the key part is finding a caret svg that you can URL convert into a string. I could enhance it a little, maybe rotate the caret somehow, but really - I'm just happy it isn't god-ugly.

Answer (score 8):

It's working in all browser:

```
select {
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
    background-position-x: 244px;

}
```

Comment: You don't consider IE a browser. I wont down-vote you for that.

Answer (score 7):

Style the label with CSS and use pointer events :

```
<label>
<select>
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
</label>
```

and the relative CSS is

```
label:after {
    content:'\25BC';
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left:-17px;   /* remove the damn :after space */
    pointer-events:none; /* let the click pass trough */
}
```

I just used a down arrow here, but you can set a block with a background image. Here is a ugly fiddle sample:  https://jsfiddle.net/1rofzz89/

Answer (score 7):

just do this:

```css
select {

    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNSIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2U9IiNiYmIiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik02IDlsNiA2IDYtNiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 100% !important;
    background-position-y: 50% !important;
    
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    -ms-appearance: none !important;
    -o-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this. Its Tested code

```
    select {
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    background-size: 25px 25px !important;
    background-position: 99% 50% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple arrow and clean code

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat 100% center;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few examples [here](https://codepen.io/samgermain-the-sasster/pen/jOrgpEL)

It's based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274325/6331353), but I added one to the list to make a design that is even more minimal

```
select.moreMinimal {

    background-color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    padding: 0 2.2em 0 1em;    
    margin: 0;      
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
  }

select.moreMinimal {
    background-image:
      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
      linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-position:
      calc(100% - 20px), 
      calc(100% - 15px);
    background-size:
      5px 5px,
      5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
//TODO: Probably shouldn't be focus, cause when you click it again it's still green
select.moreMinimal:focus {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(45deg, green 50%, transparent 50%),
        linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, green 50%);
    background-position:
        calc(100% - 15px),
        calc(100% - 20px);
    background-size:
        5px 5px,
        5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-color: green;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274325/905915), it worked like charm , except it did not hide the arrow in IE browser.

> However adding following hides the arrow in IE:

```css
&::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
```

> Complete solution ( sass )

```css
$select-border-color: #ccc;
$select-focus-color: green;

select {

    cursor: pointer;
    /* styling */
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid $select-border-color;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;

    /* reset */
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;

    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, $select-border-color 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, $select-border-color 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, $select-border-color, $select-border-color);
    background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* Very imp: hide arrow in IE */
    &::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }

    &:-moz-focusring {
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: none;
    }

    &:focus {
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, $select-focus-color 50%, transparent 50%),
      linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, $select-focus-color 50%), linear-gradient(to right, $select-focus-color, $select-focus-color);
      background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 1em, calc(100% - 20px) 1em, calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
      background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 1.5em;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border-color: $select-focus-color;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most elegant way to replace arrow:

```
select {
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  min-width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;

  /*Remove decorations to replace arrow with custom arrow */   
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;  
  &::-ms-expand { display: none };  
}
.custom-select:after {
    /* Here we add font taken from libre office to content */
    content: "▼";
    position: absolute;
    top: 4;
    /* Here we need to calculate fonts place so that if select box width changes the custom button font will be always at same place */
    left: calc(100% - 30px);
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 12px 7px;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

[Heres a Picture of it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F8vf.png)

And also run code snippet!

CSS and then HTML:

```css
           #select-category {
            font-size: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-right: 180px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            border-radius: 1000000px;
            border: 1px solid #707070;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            background: transparent;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='34' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-x: 100%;
            background-position-y: 5px;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
```

```html
                <select id="select-category">
                    <option>Category</option>
                    <option>Category 2</option>
                    <option>Category 3</option>
                    <option>Category 4</option>
                    <option>Category 5</option>
                    <option>Category 6</option>
                    <option>Category 7</option>
                    <option>Category 8</option>
                    <option>Category 9</option>
                    <option>Category 10</option>
                    <option>Category 11</option>
                    <option>Category 12</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gradients to draw the arrow. Big advantage for me is that it is simpler to theme based on other design colors vs. requiring an image or embedding SVGs in the HTML just to update the fill style.

This is a version of [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64977450/3246449) above, simplified further, parameterized, annotated and with example.

[CodePen version.](https://codepen.io/Maxim-Paperno/pen/dyryeag)

(If you're wondering about the color name used here, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/system-color )

```css
select {
  /* reset (add vendor prefixed versions if you need) */
  box-sizing: border-box;
    appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* Other styles, not required. */
  padding: 0.25em;
  
  /* The arrow -- settings */
    --arrow-pad: .25em;   /* space between arrow and border */
    --arrow-size: .5em;   /* width and height of arrow */
    --arrow-color: GrayText;  /* arrow color */
  
    --arrow-offset: calc(var(--arrow-pad) + var(--arrow-size));  /* D.R.Y. */
  
  /* Add space for arrow. */
    padding-right: calc(var(--arrow-offset) * 4) !important;

  /* The arrow - draw using 2 45° gradients with sharp edges. */
  /* Can change angles for a non-square arrow or otherwise get creative here. */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent        50%, var(--arrow-color) 50%),  /* left part of arrow */
    linear-gradient(135deg, var(--arrow-color) 50%, transparent        50%);  /* right part of arrow */
    
  /* Position the arrow on the right side taking desired padding and arrow width into account. */
  background-position:
    calc(100% - (var(--arrow-offset) * 1.5)) 50%,  /* left part of arrow */
    calc(100% - var(--arrow-offset))         50%;  /* right part of arrow */
  
  /* Declare the actual sizing of the arrow "image." */
  background-size:
    var(--arrow-size) var(--arrow-size),  /* left part of arrow */
    var(--arrow-size) var(--arrow-size);  /* right part of arrow */
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* just one arrow, please */
}
```

```html
  <select id="my-select" class="select">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could wrap a  HTML tag in the  or  tag.
Then we could apply any icons.

```css
/* CSS */
  span.select-container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
  }

  span.select-container select {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      appearance: none;
      padding: 0.25rem 0.85rem;
  }

  span.select-container::before {
      content: '\2B9F';
      position: absolute;
      width: 2rem;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 2.5rem;
      pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<span class="select-container">
  <select>
    <option disabled="">Select Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume, selectDrop is the class present in your HTML  tag.So, this much of code is enough to change default arrow icon:

```
.selectDrop{
      background: url(../images/icn-down-arrow-light.png) no-repeat right #ddd; /*To change default icon with provided image*/
      -webkit-appearance:none; /*For hiding default pointer of drop-down on Chrome*/
      -moz-appearance:none; /*For hiding default pointer of drop-down on Mozilla*/
      background-position-x: 90%; /*Adjust according to width of dropdown*/
    }
```