# css replace a combo box item in a list box with an image

Tags: html, css

I have a select tag in a div, I want to replace its "combobox drop down item" with an image that I have designed. Is there a pure css way to do it?

The codes I have for it are as follows:

```
<div id="country">
    <select>
        <option> Country:</option>
        <option>xxx</option>
        <option>yyy</option>
        <option>zzz</option>
    </select>    
<div>
```

and a css selector as follows:

```
#country select {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    border: thin solid #152635;
    width: 528px;
    height: 42px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #152635;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Comment: [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g32uyr30/), for anyone interested.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: @isim I don't want to put images in the options, I want to change the shape of the "drop down item" (the gray button with a triangle in the middle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [select arrow style change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)