# How to make both up/down arrow in select input field in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a [website](http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/) (**built on Wordpress, custom theme**) in which I want to add **up/down arrow in the select input field in CSS**. The HTML code which I am using in order to create up/down arrow for the select input field is:

```
<p>
   <select name="filter_31" id="search-box-filter_31">
      <option value="Vancouver Island University">University of A</option>
      <option value="Western University">University of B</option>
      <option value="Wilfrid Laurier University">University of C</option>
      <option value="York University">University of D</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

Here is the complete fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ovp8Lxjw/4/embedded/result for the above code. At this moment, it has only down arrow.

In the above fiddle, I want to add both up/down arrow of blue color. At this moment, it shows only down arrow.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS code I need to add in the above fiddle so that I can see **up/down arrow** (**as shown in the screenshot below, marked by an arrow**) in the select input field in css. I can't make any changes in the HTML code as it is coming from inspect from the wordpress [website](http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/).

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change This will help you

Comment: @Francesco Fortin It didn't help much. I need to make both up/down arrow in select input field in css. The above question has only one down arrow.

Comment: The screenshot you posted is from OSX, and you want it to also display that same up/down arrow on other operating systems like Windows?  @FrancescoFortin looks correct but you'd need to supply your image to have the up and down arrow there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple and straight-forward example using a base64-encoded Font Awesome icon as background image for the select box.

```css
select {
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
select.arrows {
  background-image:    url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAA3klEQVRIS+3VMU9CMRTF8d8zBL+aizoQFhx0kUk33RzdYMNFXUFnYeGrYYyaJiUxJHDLSxodbNKpfeffc9/pbaPyaCrr+3OA++z4rtT5Pg5GuMnCY9yWQEoBE1xhlUUP8YDrCBIB0vojLvGO0yz4hm4JJAKcYYoPHGOZAUdYoIMBXrc5iQAHeMlzviFygj7O8dkWEJU4XI8chALRhn9AVKHf70VRTHu4wFfbmKZLNKt50dLBnna0imcMd/2I0phWa3Y/D1e1Xa9BCZJG0VuQNpaWKMx72xS1Fl5/WN3BN+AgJhnZQlq4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-position: calc(100% - .5rem), 100% 0;
  background-size:  1.5em 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

select.arrows:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select class="arrows">
      <option value="Vancouver Island University">Vancouver Island University</option>
      <option value="Western University">Western University</option>
      <option value="Wilfrid Laurier University">Wilfrid Laurier University</option>
      <option value="York University">York University</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

You can check this in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovp8Lxjw/20/)

In addition a link to [Icomoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), used to create the png image of the icon used.

Comment: Checking. Stay tuned.

Comment: @john i think you won't have a problem. It will look the same on most browsers if not all. It was checked on Edge,FF,Opera and Chrome (for Win desktop).

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I think it worked. I have awarded the bounty as well. I have one more similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685059/how-to-ignore-the-specific-css-codes-coming-from-the-wordpress-plugin-stylesheet/52685274?noredirect=1#comment92299928_52685274). I am wondering if you can have a look. It is something related wordpress plugin css. I am stuck on this from the last 24 hours

Answer (score 9):

The default select arrow icon is drawn by the browser. There is no API for you to tell the browser to replace the arrow icon, so you will need to restyle the select element and overlay your own arrows. You can draw your own arrows that have an identical style to your browser's arrows, but remember that the default icon will differ for other browsers and operating systems.

To restyle the select item using only CSS you will need to target both the select and its parent `p` element. The select has an ID, which is easy to target, but targeting that specific `p` element is not easy from just the code you've provided. However looking at the provided Wordpress site link there is a label just before the `p`, of the form `<label for="search-box-filter_31">Name of Institution</label>`. This means that the `p` element can be targeted using the CSS selector `label[for=search-box-filter_31] + p`.

You first need to ensure you have enough space for your new arrow. This is accomplished by increasing the select's width by the width of your new arrows, and adding the same amount to the parent `p`'s right padding. One way to change the select's width is by using `calc(100% + 30px)`. If your new arrows have the same width as the default icons you may not need to do this, but in some configurations your arrows may overlap the select's content.

Additionally the `p` element must shrink to fit its content. There are a few ways of doing this, but in your situation the one least likely to break formatting is setting `display: table`.

Finally, you can use the `::after` pseudo element on `p` to create the desired arrows, and overlay it on the end of your select element, hiding the default arrow. In the example below I created the arrows with inline SVG, but you can use any background image that best suits your situation. Set the `::after` element to have `position:absolute` and style it to fit exactly over the right hand side of the select. To create the blue gradient background under the arrows that you have in your image, use multiple backgrounds with the first being your arrows and the second being a CSS gradient.

Note that since the `::after` element is on top of the select, clicking the arrows will not display the options. You can set `pointer-events: none;` to pass the clicks through but this will not work on IE.

The CSS is below, or alternatively you can see it at the codepen https://codepen.io/jla-/pen/ZqbWMj

```
#search-box-filter_31 {
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
label[for=search-box-filter_31] + p {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
label[for=search-box-filter_31] + p::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><polyline points='8,12,15,8,22,12' fill='none' style='stroke:white;stroke-width:2'/><polyline points='8,18,15,22,22,18' fill='none' style='stroke:white;stroke-width:2'/></svg>"),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, #a0d8ff 0%, #2591dd 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The result (followed by the default select as it appears in Firefox on Linux):

[image]

Of course, the arrows and their blue background can be styled in any other way that you wish. Please note that adding a custom style to the select arrows will make it look different to the default browser style. You can style it to fit in seamlessly in one browser, e.g. Chrome, but another browser, e.g. Firefox, will display things differently and your custom style will not match. To have a seamless appearance across all browsers and operating systems you would need to make sure all select/input elements are styled to match each other.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to pure CSS / HTML is available, but works through the hack when we extend the height through html size = "2" and then again narrow it through the height:

```html
<p>
   <select name="filter_31" id="search-box-filter_31" size="2" style="font-size:16px; height:24px;">
      <option value="Vancouver Island University">University of Arizona</option>
      <option value="Western University">University of B</option>
      <option value="Wilfrid Laurier University">University of C</option>
      <option value="York University">University of D</option>
   </select>
</p>
```

But I would not write such a code for a working project, instead it's better to use the js library, for example:
https://github.hubspot.com/select/docs/welcome/

Comment: I can't make any changes in the html code because that's all coming from wordpress after doing inspect. The only place where I can do changes is the CSS. I am wondering if you know CSS which can solve it.

Comment: This task can not be solved only by CSS. You will need javascript anyway. Any solution to this problem only using CSS will cause problems in different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: Let's decide first, do you just need an icon on the right with up and down arrows, so that a dropdown will appear when you click on the arrows? Or do you need these arrows to be fully-fledged workers, that is, a separate behavior for these two arrows? It would be better if you find a working example of what you want on the web, perhaps on some site and add a link to your question.

Comment: Your first point makes sense to me. I need an icon on the right with up and down arrows of blue color and a drop-down should appear when we click on the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the after: selector on the p element.

```
p:after{
content: url("path/to/image");
}
```

Comment: We have limited options as we can't change the html. Only option left is css.

Comment: The example I posted is CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I am just telling.

Comment: You are using an image for the arrows, correct? This should definitely work for you.

Comment: Thats all coming from wordpress forms. I am not using anything.

Answer (score 0):

May be this gives you some comfort as you say you can't touch the HTML. I was playing with CSS!

```
#search-box-filter_32 {
            background-color: white !important;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/trico-arrows-1/24/ExpandUpDownSmall-512.png') no-repeat right #ddd;
            background-position: 98%;
            padding: 2px 20px 2px 8px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            background-size: 14px;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -o-appearance: none;
            -ms-appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            outline: none !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px  solid #cccccc;
        }
```

https://codepen.io/mohan-wijesena/pen/dgMBLY