# how can css for select on Safari same Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select like this:

```html
<select id="sbInBreak2_hh" name="sbInBreak2_hh">
 <option value="0">00</option>
 <option value="1">01</option>
 <option value="2">02</option>
 <option value="3">03</option>
 <option value="4">04</option>
 <option value="5">05</option>
 <option value="6">06</option>
 <option value="7">07</option>
 <option value="8">08</option>
 <option value="9">09</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 <option value="12">12</option>
 <option value="13">13</option>
 <option value="14">14</option>
 <option value="15">15</option>
 <option value="16">16</option>
 <option value="17">17</option>
 <option value="18">18</option>
 <option value="19">19</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="21">21</option>
 <option value="22">22</option>
 <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

On the Chrome it is Ok, the PM required me display on the Safari and IE same on the Chrome? How can css for it?

On Chrome

[image]

On Safari and IE

[image]

Comment: Is the question how you can style a select field?

Comment: You have a display in all browser, so what the problem ?

Comment: You can see, the imager down on the Chrome is not same on the Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try like this.
```

```css
select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
select {
    box-shadow:none;   
    outline:none;      
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSdibGFjaycgaGVpZ2h0PScyNCcgdmlld0JveD0nMCAwIDI0IDI0JyB3aWR0aD0nMjQnIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2Zyc+PHBhdGggZD0nTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXonLz48cGF0aCBkPSdNMCAwaDI0djI0SDB6JyBmaWxsPSdub25lJy8+PC9zdmc+);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 21px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 44px;
}
/*select::-ms-expand { display: none; }*/
```

```html
<select id="sbInBreak2_hh" name="sbInBreak2_hh" style="width:44px;">
 <option value="0">00</option>
 <option value="1">01</option>
 <option value="2">02</option>
 <option value="3">03</option>
 <option value="4">04</option>
 <option value="5">05</option>
 <option value="6">06</option>
 <option value="7">07</option>
 <option value="8">08</option>
 <option value="9">09</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 <option value="12">12</option>
 <option value="13">13</option>
 <option value="14">14</option>
 <option value="15">15</option>
 <option value="16">16</option>
 <option value="17">17</option>
 <option value="18">18</option>
 <option value="19">19</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="21">21</option>
 <option value="22">22</option>
 <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `-webkit-appearance:none`; and using background-image for select.

Comment: có nhiều cách mà bạn. Bạn có thể làm 1 cái border arrow hoặc tìm 1 cái image arrow giống thế kia cũng được.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can add the following CSS to prevent the "highlighted" effect on IE and Safari:

```
#sbInBreak2_hh,
#sbInBreak2_hh:focus {
    box-shadow:none;   /* Prevent blurred border */
    outline:none;      /* Prevent hard outline */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how can display button inner fill black same chrome?

Comment: You're welcome - sorry not sure what you mean by inner fill? Do you mean change the white background to black background?

Comment: I mean: triangular on Chrome is difference vs Safari

Comment: @HongVanVit have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change