# How to change icon in drop down?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, dropdown, reusability

This is a drop-down I'm using in my React project.I want to change the default arrow into another one and add styles. Is there a way to customize this ?

```
<Col>
                  <select
                    id="dropdown-2"
                    value={this.state.priority}
                    onChange={this.handlePriority}
                    style={{
                      paddingRight: 115,
                      paddingTop: 10,
                      paddingBottom: 10,
                      borderRadius: 5,
                      background: 'white',
                      borderColor: '#cdd0cb',
                      paddingLeft: 15
                    }}
                  >
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                  </select>
                </Col>
```

Comment: Guess this topic will help you: [Arrow style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select arrow style change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)