# html selector custom arrow

Tags: html, css

I am want to change my selector arrow icon. So far I disabled the default appearance and added the arrow, from the link, below:

- https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=arrow

Obviously I do not find my mistake, further I added an !important tag too, in case a rule overrides the setup. So currently there is no arrow.

And idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Neumorphism</title>
    <!-- import "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    section {
        line-height: 2em;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 350px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        border-radius: 10px;

    }

  

    input::placeholder,
    textarea::placeholder {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
        color: inherit;
    }

    hr {
        color: white;
        height: 3px;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    h5, label {
        margin: .5em 0;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    button,
    select {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-delay: .2s;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    button:active,
    select {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    select {
        appearance: none;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 1em center !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-right: 3em;
        background-size: 1.2em;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }

    .lightgreen {
        color: lightgreen;
    }

    .red {
        color: red
    }

    .border-round {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .box-shadow {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
    }

    .modal {
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        min-height: 100px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        width: 33%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <section class="modal box-shadow">
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Beziehung</h5>
        <hr class="border-round">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <label>Quelle --- </label>
            <select>
                <option>erfordert</option>
                <option>nutzt</option>
            </select>
            <label> --- Ziel</label>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-check-circle lightgreen"></i> Speichern</button>
            <button class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-times-circle red"></i> Schließen</button></button>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select arrow style change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the `select` css, working example:

The background image's position and size was not set correctly.

The changes include:

- Setting the `background-position`, `background-size`, and `background-repeat` properties of `select`, and removing arbitrary CSS properties from the same selector.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Neumorphism</title>
    <!-- import "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    section {
        line-height: 2em;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 350px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        border-radius: 10px;

    }

  

    input::placeholder,
    textarea::placeholder {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
        color: inherit;
    }

    hr {
        color: white;
        height: 3px;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    h5, label {
        margin: .5em 0;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    button,
    select {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
        transition-delay: .2s;
        transition-duration: .2s;
        color: #7b7e8c
    }

    button:active,
    select {
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 transparent, 0 0 transparent, inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -3px -3px 5px white;
        background: #f8f9fb;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-duration: .1s;
    }

    select {
        appearance: none;
        background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAMi0lEQVR4nO3d6Y9laV0H8Fs9M/rSuec5VQUOCMIIiCyBAUKAYNP3PKe6kbCmgiCOXc9zqhwX3A0hLhQJIS4ZISSEkCEIhLAoxPi3KPsmIIvsuzAD4ouepm3s6anl3vu7y+eTnPfnfPtJfb+pW33PaAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAc1dZk2G5zvXN028FN0fcCs3TrhZf/bNvVf9ju79iKvheAUFuTYTvl8sGU649T3nu/EcDK2t39mXGu/5py/XHq6r8ZAcDaurr8L1/ln40AVs5tBzeNu/ovV511IwBYR9cu/0tXm4f3js4e3hh9jzAVtx3clPLe+6911o0AYK1cr/wvX02u7zYCWHq3HdyU+vq+6511IwBYC0cp/ysjoLzLCGBpnT28sc31n45y1o0AYKUdp/yv/GAc3jna3b0h+t7hWM4e3th29T3HO+tGALCCTlT+917jXN9hBLA0zh7e2OTyrpOcdSMAWCmnKf8r197bjAAW3u7uDakb3nmqs24EAKtgOuV/+SpvHR0enol+Jrim3d0bxrm+Yypn3QgAltl0y//S1ebhLUYAC2d394bUD2+f5lk3AoClNIvyvzIC6l1GAAvj8PBMmtR/nMVZNwKApTLL8r98NV15sxFAuMPDM20e3jLLs24EAEthHuV/5RreNBqNNqKfmTV1eHimzfWuuZx1IwBYZPMt/5/8YHzjyAhg3g4PzzRdefOcz7oRACyekPK/fPXDG0ZGAPOzkfLwppCzbgQAi2bclwspl3tCfiheul4/MgKYvY3U1TfGnfNyd5NLHx0CwFVSN7wwcgS0/fC6kRHA7GykfnhDZPmnbnhedAgA1xQ+AnK9c2QEMH0bKdfXK3+A64geAU1f/35kBDA9G20/vE75AxxB9AhIuf7tyAjg9DbaXO9U/gDHED8C9l47MgI4uY2mG/5O+QOcQPgI6OtrRkYAx7eRcv0b5Q9wCtEjoM311dEZsFQ2Ut57rfIHmILoEdB05VXRGbAUNlJfX6P8AaYofATk+tfRGbDY2lxfrfwBZiB6BKS+/mV0BiympiuvUv4AM7QAI+CV0RmwWJo8/JXyB5iD8BGQ6yuiM2AxpG74C+UPMEfRI6Dty59HZ0Cs1NdXKn+AAOEjIA9/Gp0BMVKur1D+AIGiR0DT1z+OzoD5arv6Z8ofYAGEj4Bc/zA6A+ajyeVPlD/AAokeAakrL4/OgNlquvJHyh9gAYWPgDz8XnQGzEbqhz9Q/gALLHwEdMPvRGfAdKWu/r7yB1gC0SOgzfW3ozNgOlJff1f5AyyR8BHQlf3oDDidNpc7lD/AEooeAU1fanQGnEzbDwfKH2CJBY+A/2m6YS86A46nyXVQ/gArIHoEpL7+VnQGHE3T16L8AVZI+AjI9TejM+D6Ui4X7/23Uv4AqyR+BAwvi86Aa0tduV35A6yw0BHQlR+1XX1pdAZcLeXhZcofYA2Ej4C+/np0BlzS9uU3Uld+FFT+9yh/gDmLHgFNP7w4OoN11+bhJcofYA3FjoD6wybX3egM1lXTDy9W/gBrLHwEdOVF0RmsmybX3dTVHyp/gDUX+78Dyj0plxdEZ7Aumq68SPkD8BPhI0AxzJx/YwCuKbgg7m5zeW50Bqsq9fX5yh+A+xQ+Avr950RnsGraXJ6r/AG4X8F/GPiDzTw8OzqDVdH2+89Judyt/AE4kugR0Ezq+egMll3b1V9LXf2B8gfgWIK/LOj7Tbe/E53Bshr35YLyB+DEwkdALn10BsummdTzqSvfV/4AnErkCGhy/e/UlS46g2XR5NIrfwCmJnwE5DqJzmDRpa5092al/AGYntgRMHyv3SnPis5gUaVcJ8ofgJkJHQFd+W6b9341OoNF0+6UZzV5+J7yB2CmokfAZl+fGZ3Bomi74azyB2BuYkdA/c64K8+IziDaZl+f2XTlu8ofgLmK/ZuA8u1xrk+PziDKuCvPaLr6HeUPQIjoEdD0+0+LzmDexrk+vcnl28ofgFDBHwd8q+mGp0ZnMC9Nv/805Q/Awgh+d8A30059SnQGs9Z0w1Obrn5L+QOwUIJfJfyNNNl/cnQGs5J26lNSV7+p/AFYSNEjoM3lSdEZTFua7D855fIN5Q/AQosdAfXr7c7eE6MzmJY2lycpfwCWRvBbBL+22dUnRGdwWu3O3hNTrl9X/gAsleAR8NWtnfL46AxOarOrT0hd+ZryB2ApBX8c8JXxZHhcdAbHtbVTHp+68tWw8u/r86MzAGAFRI6ANpcvj7uLj43O4KjGk+FxKdevKH8AVkL4COjrY6IzuD/j7uJj21y+rPwBWCnBXxb0pWZn/1eiM7gv474+RvkDsLKCXyX8X81k79HRGfy0ZrL36NTVLyl/AFZa8AuEvpj6g0dFZ3BZ6oZfbnL5ovIHYC2EjoC+fqE9Xx4ZnkF/8CjlD8DaCf444PPtZP8RUc/eni+PbPr6BeUPwFqK/Tigfm4zX/yleT9zO9l/RNOVzyt/ANZa7JcFDf+5uVNvndezbu7UW5tcP6f8AWAUPQLKZ7fOHTx81s+4de7g4SmXzyp/APg/gr8n4DPbXXnYrJ5tuysPS139jPIHgGuI/U3A3qdvPn/xodN+pp/rh19Mee/Tyh8AriN0BEzqp24+Vx8yrWe5+fzFh6Zc/0P5A8ARhL47oCufHHcHv3DaZ7j5XH1ImtRPKX8AOIbg/yL4iabfe/BJ773p9x7cduWTyh8ATiD044C+fry5MDzouPfcXBge1OT6CeUPAKcQOQLGXflYOnf7LUe+13O335L6+nHlDwBTEPxxwEfbXH7+fu/x3O23NLl+VPkDwBTFvjugfrjdOXjgfd1bu3PwwCaXjyh/AJiB4BcIfWjz7MUH/PQ9bZ69+ICmqx9W/gAwQ8FfG/zBrcmwffletibDdtOVDyl/AJiD2BFQP7Dd37G1NRm2U64fUP4AMEfBXxv875cu5Q8Acxf8mwDlDwBR1mcEKH8AuMrqjwDlDwDXtLojQPkDwHWt3ggo96RcXhCdKwAsvNUZAcofAI5l+UeA8geAE1neEaD8AeBUlm8EKH8AmIrlGQHKHwCmavFHgPIHgJlY3BGg/AFgphZvBCh/AJiLxRkByh8A5ip+BCh/AAgRNwKUPwCEmv8IUP4AsBDmNwKUPwAslNmPAOUPAAtpdiNA+QPAQpv+CFD+ALAUpjcClD8ALJXTjwDlDwBL6eQjQPkDwFI7/ghQ/gCwEo4+ApQ/AKyU+x8Byh8AVtJ9jwDlDwAr7f+PAOUPAGvhyghQ/gCwVu4dAcofAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFhl/wvAMV8MmL0UcAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        background-size: 1.8em;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }

    .lightgreen {
        color: lightgreen;
    }

    .red {
        color: red
    }

    .border-round {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .box-shadow {
        box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
    }

    .modal {
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        min-height: 100px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: #f2f3f7;
        width: 33%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <section class="modal box-shadow">
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Beziehung</h5>
        <hr class="border-round">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <label>Quelle --- </label>
            <select>
                <option>erfordert</option>
                <option>nutzt</option>
            </select>
            <label> --- Ziel</label>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-check-circle lightgreen"></i> Speichern</button>
            <button class="border-round"><i class="fas fa-times-circle red"></i> Schließen</button></button>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be cool if you could explain your answer a little bit!

Comment: @AjithGopi I tried to set all attributes in one line. LS instead splitted those attributes and defined a size, which I didn´t had at all.

Comment: @AjithGopi yes sorry I always try to add an explanation but I was in a rush and sometimes code changes are self-explanatory. Thanks for adding the informations :)