# How to change the arrow icon from a select list

Tags: html, css

I want wo change this icon from my select list [image]

into this icon [image]

I tried several code from stackoverflow with this type of question but they don't work.

Comment: Select isn't custumizable element you have to create a fake one. You use some html/css framework like bootstrap or another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select arrow style change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)

Comment: i don't know any frameworks, so it's impossible with pure css?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-selects-in-2019/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `appearnace: none` CSS property, with `::after` selector. You can use custom symbol, inside `::after` using `content` property.

```css
div {
  position: relative;  
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 50px 33%;
}


div::after {
  content: '>';
  font: 17px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: #333;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 15px;
  top: 18px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
      <select>
          <option selected> Select Box </option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```