# Change HTML Select arrow background color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a select menu with options

In Firefox, it has an "arrow button"
[image]

In Chrome/Edge, it doesn't

[image]

How do I make it so that the Firefox "expand menu" button looks like Chrome/Edge?

```
<select>
<option>Example</option>
<option>Example</option>
<option>Example</option>
<option>Example</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your Firefox browser is up to date right ?

Comment: Try using CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some `linear-gradient` `background-image` hacks:

```css
select {
  /* styling */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

select.classic {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, black, black);
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), 100% 0;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 2.5em 2.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<select class="classic">
  <option>Option</option>
  <option>Option</option>
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cool! I just want to keep the arrow but get rid of the button around. The extra CSS for colors will be covered by something else

Comment: @SteveAlereza I've updated the answer to include less unnecessary CSS. Some padding is required for positioning though.