# Custom dropdown arrow

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to change the dropdown arrow of the select tag to a custom arrow consisting of 4 elements. I want to make it like this: 3 horizontal lines on the left and a down arrow on the right

I managed to do it with only one element (one horizontal line)

```
    .select-wrapper::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        display: block;
        width: 9px;
        height: 2px;
        background: black;
    }
```

Comment: If you mean changing the visual, I suggest to get the icon element and change it to your curstom icon that you should probably create by your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to acheive something similar to [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/papapps/pen/ZEVzmPy). The code almost entirely taken from SVNM's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change)

### Edits from that answer

- Using an image to make the lines/arrow you describe although SVG may be better if you know how to do it
- Positioning and size of the background image

### Example HTML for this

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

### CSS

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://paul7dxb.github.io/hosted-assets/SomePNGs/arrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-position-x: 80%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
```