# Does select's box transparent background work in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, firefox

I am trying to make select's box background transparent through css. I am using `background-color:transparent;`. It is working for firefox but not for chrome. Any idea? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DNA180/6Chzm/2/) is a live example. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Chrome 25.0.1364.172 - Works for the select, not for the options

Comment: @Bigood I'm using the same version of Chrome as you and the transparency *doesn't* work on either. For reference, solid colours work fine, but the alpha transparency is ignored too. `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` displays as `rgb(255,0,0)`.

Comment: Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m - Doesn't work on either for me

Comment: @Bigood: Is it working for you using `background-color:transparent;`???

Comment: @DNA180: you've just had two people using the exact same version telling you it doesn't. If it does indeed work for him it's probably some browser extension allowing it to happen.

Comment: I must correct myself : the `select` is black transparent : the `background-color` have an effect on it, as it is white if the property isn't applied. It is not fully transparent like Tyriar's fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find `-webkit-appearance: none;` useful. `<select>`s are notoriously difficult to style, you may want to consider making your own if you're after a non-custom look and feel.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/bsSV4/)

```
.outter_div select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Good shout! You may want to add that this only styles the `select` and not the `option`s.

Comment: It looks like it is the only way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5972981/1156119 http://stackoverflow.com/a/4142698/1156119

Comment: I'll wait a bit more and if we don't get any better answer, I'll set this question as the correct answer!