# Is it possible to style dropdown select arrow differently to entire box using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to alter the background colour of a arrow of a html select box using just CSS?

I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBjpp.png

So far I've got:

css:

```
.sort-by select {
width:100px;
border:0px;
background-color:#f4f4f4;
color:#303030;
padding:5px;
}
```

html:

```
<select title="Sort By">
<option value="" selected="selected">Value 1</option>
<option value="">Value 2</option>
<option value="">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Which gives me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj8yF.png

However I can't seem to find a way to alter just the background colour behind the arrow? Anyone got any advice that would be great! Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change/14218448#14218448

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)