# How to rotate/spin 180' the caret from the dropdown ideally with just CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I rotate upside down (180') the caret from the dropdown menu when clicked, so that when clicking the dropdown it almost looks like an animation?

It would be great if that could be done without javascript and just CSS, but open to any suggestion.

```css
.select {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="city_select_dropdown_container">
  <div>
    <span style="color:white;font-size:12px">City</span>
    <form>
      <select class="select">
        <option>Option 1 </option>
        <option>Option 2 </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to modify the CSS inside this div/form, but It does not let me.

Comment: Not with a `select`.  You'll need to use a third-party drop down which draws this in its own div with an icon (image or sprite)

Comment: Thanks, with Javascript will there be way to do that by keeping the select ? (The reason of keeping select being is that I am going to link those select into my django apps forms and models)?

Comment: No idea about django, but many third-party dropdowns work by converting/hiding an underlying `select` - so...probably.

Comment: might this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142619/how-to-make-select-element-be-transparent-in-chrome/

Comment: @Asturion, this is a good partial solution, however you can not change onclick the image.

Comment: @SkylerX what for yo need click event? you can make css for focused state using :focus selector

Comment: @Asturion, so that when you click it back it will spin back to its original position, or if you click something else, however I think, that there is no way of doing it without Javascript or Jquery.

Comment: @SkylerX if you need events support  then it is better to use third party plugins/ but anyway you can style it with simple css selectors :hover :focus etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or with smaller script

```js
$(document).on('click','.select',function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('focused');
})
```

```css
.select {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  width:100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height:45px;
  padding: 0 3em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
   -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}
.selector {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  }
.selector::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
  top:50%;
  border-right:2px solid black;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  margin-top:-2.5px;
  position:absolute;
  right:1em;
  color:#000;
  z-index:2;
}

.selector.focused::before{
  transform:rotate(0);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="city_select_dropdown_container">
  <div>
    <span style="color:black;font-size:12px">City</span>
    <form>
    <div class="selector">
      <select class="select">
        <option>Option 1 </option>
        <option>Option 2 </option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```